# How do I convert a string to f32?

Tags: type-conversion, rust

I'm just started to learn rust and have problem with conversion from string to f32.
In nightly 0.11 was function "from_str" and i use it like this:

```
let f = std::f32::from_str("0.11", 10);
```

In current 1.0.0 alpha function not exists.
How to convert from str to f32 now?

Comment: Maybe `let temp: f32 = temp.to_string().parse()?;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use [parse](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse), now.

```
let f = "0.11".parse::<f32>(); // returns a Result<f32, std::num::ParseFloatError>`
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent half a day on this :)

Comment: Things have changed since this answer was given; this now returns a `std::result::Result<f32, std::num::ParseFloatError>` instead of an `Option<f32>` (using Rust 1.44.1).

Comment: `s.parse::<f32>().unwrap();` still works.